# Get selected index from 2d array grid in Processing

Tags: multidimensional-array, grid, click, processing

**I want to create a peg solitaire game based on a 2d array in Processing.**

I've succeeded to create the board and pawns.[image: board and pawn layout]

Now i want to get the index from a pawn by clicking on it and be able to move it around the board.

**Here is what i have now to create the image above.**

```
/**
 * Gameboard array
 * 0 = non playable squares
 * 1 = empty square
 * 2 = pawn
 **/

int[][] gameboard = {
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0},
  {0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0},
  {0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
};

boolean checkIfGameboardFits() {
  return AMOUNT * SIDE < SCREENWIDTH && AMOUNT * SIDE < SCREENHEIGHT;
}

void giveErrorMessage() {
  println("/ Gameboard doesnt fit the screen");
}

void drawGameboard(int xPos, int yPos, int[][] gameboard) {
  for (int row = 0; row < AMOUNT; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < AMOUNT; column++) {
      int xPosSquare = xPos + (column * SIDE);
      int yPosSquare = yPos + (row * SIDE);
      switch (gameboard[row][column]) {
      case 0:
        fill(#760000);
        break;
      case 1:
        fill(#FFFFFF);
        break;
      case 2:
        fill(#9B9999);
        break;
      }
      rect(xPosSquare, yPosSquare, SIDE, SIDE);
    }
  }
}

void drawBoardPieces(int xPos, int yPos, int[][] gameboard) {
  for (int row = 0; row < AMOUNT; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < AMOUNT; column++) {
      if (gameboard[row][column] == 2) {
        fill(#FFFFFF);
        circle(xPos + (column * SIDE) + PAWNMARGE, yPos + (row * SIDE) + PAWNMARGE, PAWNSIZE);
      }
    }
  }
}

void startGame() {
  background(255);
  gameState = 1;

  if (checkIfGameboardFits()) {
    int startXposGameboard = (width - (AMOUNT * SIDE)) /2;
    int startYposGameboard = (height - (AMOUNT * SIDE)) /2;
    drawGameboard(startXposGameboard, startYposGameboard, gameboard);
    drawBoardPieces(startXposGameboard, startYposGameboard, gameboard);
  } else {
    giveErrorMessage();
  }
}
```

And the rest of the code.

```
final int SIDE = 60;
final int AMOUNT = 9;

final int SCREENWIDTH = 800;
final int SCREENHEIGHT = 800;

final int PAWNSIZE = 40;
final int PAWNMARGE = 30;

int gameState;

void settings() {
  size(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);
}
void setup() {
  startGame();
}

void draw() {
}   

void mousePressed() {
  // get index and value from clicked square
}
```

Any and all tips, examples or thinking processes would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the index by dividing the relative mouse position by the size of a tile:

```java
void mousePressed() {
   
    int column = (mouseX - xPos) / SIDE;
    int row    = (mouseY - yPos) / SIDE;

    if (column >= 0 && column < AMOUNT && row >= 0 && row < AMOUNT) {
        // mouse is on the board at column and row
        // ... 
    }
}
```